# How can I fully integrate my Windows files with Ubuntu using dual boot setup?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I am totally new to Linux/Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Win7 from a USB stick. I was under the impression that doing this would allow me to access my files from within Ubuntu just as I've always done using Windows.

However, although I can still access the files easily from the Windows partition in the file manager, the files are not fully integrated into my Ubuntu environment. I.e. whenever I want to use them, I have to navigate to the Windows partition. E.g. I would like to 'import' my existing music files - which right now are in my Music folder in Windows - into Rhythmbox, to make playlists, etc. But I cannot! The best I can do is navigate to the Win partition and open the files individually from there.

What I want is for all my files to 'just be there' for me in Ubuntu as they are in Windows, without having to always navigate to my Windows partition. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any guidance you can give.

Comment: You have to navigate to your files in windows as well, like in any other operating system. It's up to your software to know where to look for files, what's stopping you from setting up rythmbox to use your windows partition by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your Windows partition automatically mounted to Ubuntu by editing the `/etc/fstab` if i'm correct.but it won't mount untill you logged in
so here are the steps

1-Open terminal and run `blkid` as super user

2-you will see several line of partition UUID.keep it open and open new terminal

3-now run `gedit /etc/fstab` also as super user

4-now on the bottomest line or make new line if there isn't any and type 
`UUID=`(your windows partition UUID)

5.followed by *space* (partition mount point) *space* (filesystem type,so i assume you also want to write to Windows partiition so you can use `ntfs-3g` for the filesystem type) *space*  `defaults`  *space* `0` *space* `0`

well that i usually do
And with this you not only can read from windows partition but also wrtite to it,but Windows partition will not mounted if it isn't *clean* yet or you're not logged in yet

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a symbolic link for the folder( which contains music files in ntfs partition) in the default Ubuntu Music folder.To do this run the below command in terminal,

```
ln -s /path/to/the/folder/which/contains/music/files/present/in/the/ntfs/partition ~/Music
```

Now you can access the ntfs music folder inside the default Ubuntu Music folder.

Answer (score 0):

While this probably isn’t best solution, copy-pasting from Windows partition to home folder in Ubuntu may solve your issue.

Although is unclear from your question if you wanna keep the files in Windows partition or  not. I assume that you're using partition map without specific "data" partition in Windows, it means physically your files are  burned in Windows installation on Windows partition.

Note that some programs may help you in this for example Shotwell can be pointed to specific folder to read your photo information but it can also read photo information and copy photos on Ubuntu partition whenever you point it (by default photos will be imported to pictures folder).

When dual booting I usually have a third data partition for files I wanna use on both OS installations. I point nautilus to the files (same as Windows). In nautilus you can achieve that by installing gconf-editor using

`sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`

run it and choose <kbd>apps</kbd>, <kbd>nautilus</kbd> <kbd>preferences</kbd>. When location of files adjusted as per your  needs tick always use location entry to make it permanent.